# How can I trigger a button inside a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger a button (inside one  of my table) when the user clicks on a `<tr>` tag object, as below:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').on('click', 'tr', function(){
        var tridx = $(this).data('track-id');
        $('td div#play'+tridx).click();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-sort="nope">id</th>
          <th data-sort="name">Artist</th>
          <th data-sort="name">Title</th>
          <th data-sort="name">Genre</th>
          <th data-sort="duration">Duration</th>
          <th data-sort="date">Release</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>      
     <tr data-track-id="252">   
      <td>
       <div data-track-name="1" data-track-id="252" id="play252" class="playbtn252" style="display: none;"></div>
       <div id="countlist252" data-count-list="1" style="display: block;">1</div>
      </td>
            <td>Simon Deoro</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3:47</td>
            <td>2016-12-06</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more tr -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The `tridx` is correct, however I get this error from console:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What's wrong in my code, I cannot understand it seems everything correct to me?

Comment: `$('td div#play'+tridx).click();`???

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried also a simple  `$('#play'+tridx).click();` but it's not working

Comment: No, why are you doing that at first point? That's crazy.

Comment: When you are using `$('td div#play'+tridx).click();` event is propagating to `tr`, seems you are stuck in continuous loop

Comment: There might be too many `tr` in your body. Delegating events on you body to too many `tr` can cause the `stackoverflow` ;)

Comment: You are causing a recursive click event. You could try `$('td div#play'+tridx)[0].click();` to bypass the jQuery event handler and hit the DOM click instead.

Comment: When triggering the click on the `div` the `click` event is fired to this and bubbles up the complete DOM tree, including the `tr`.

Comment: Your functions are calling themselves recursively! :O

Comment: @nashcheez even with few `tr` in page, I get the same error

Comment: @nashcheez: That is so wrong, it is not right :) The number of TRs does not cause this problem. A recursively generated event does.

Comment: Also `var tridx = $(this).attr('data-track-id');`

Comment: @philantrovert: That is the same as `$(this).data('track-id')`

Comment: @GoneCoding Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Yes I recall the cause of this as a recursive event call in a loop. Had faced similar issues long time back and remember having sleepless nights over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, the cause is recursively generating a click event on an element inside the same TR.

Just check that the click event is not from the play button before clicking the play button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
    var tridx = $(this).data('track-id');
    var $button = $('td div#play'+tridx);
    if (!$button.is(e.target))
    {
        $button.click();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @SimonLeCat: Other options include using sentinel flags, but this is simplest.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your function call (handling the `click` event) going recursive.

jQuery's `.on(...)` is capturing the click event for the specified selector (`tr` in your case) *and everything beneath it*.  So the `click` event of the button *inside* the `tr` also fires the anonymous function you've defined.

In your scenario this is **not desirable** because the user's click triggers another `click` event, triggering another `click` event, and so on.

Every call to a function from inside a function generates a new entry on the call stack, which eventually grows too big and falls over.  (That's the symptom you're seeing.)  The stack shrinks back down only when a function actually returns... (which is never happening for you).

There are various ways you could avoid this problem.  Possibly simplest: just forget having a click handler on the button itself (as the button's click triggers the containing `tr` click event anyway).

Alternatively you could tell jQuery to stop applying the click event up the DOM tree...

Quoting the jQuery documentation on this subject:

> By default, most events bubble up from the original event target to
>   the document element.
>
> At each element along the way, jQuery calls any
>   matching event handlers that have been attached. A handler can prevent
>   the event from bubbling further up the document tree (and thus prevent
>   handlers on those elements from running) by calling
>   `event.stopPropagation()`.
>
> Any other handlers attached on the current
>   element will run however.
>
> To prevent that, call
>   `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. (Event handlers bound to an element
>   are called in the same order that they were bound.)

**Cite:** http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

On a semi-related note, I'd strongly recommend structuring your jQuery code in a way which makes separation of event handlers vs private methods vs public methods as clear as possible.  There's a variety of "recommendations" (I certainly can't say standards!) on how to do it - my personal favourite is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947280/817132

Using this method, I create a "namespace" for all the UI code (assuming it's only a small codebase) and have one "setup" function (invoked by `onReady`) which connects all the event handlers to their relevant selectors.  Those event handlers are as minimal as possible, mostly invoking private functions containing the real logic.

As a matter of *personal* preference, I avoid anonymous functions as much as possible.  I attach references to functions instead.

---

On a semi-semi related note ... if you've not already, I would **strongly** recommend getting to grips with your browser's developer tools.  (My personal favourite is that which ships with Chrome.)

Specifically look into **breakpoints** and learn how to **step** line by line (and in and out of functions) while using **watches**.

For example: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints

Comment: You're welcome.  I've added a note about structuring code ... it's not really relevant as an answer to your question - but I guarantee you a better experience in the medium/long-term if you start now.  Anonymous functions can become a bit of a mare for debugging, especially in situations like this.  If you're not already familiar with it - I'd also get a grasp on using your browser's developer tools for setting debug breakpoints to step through execution line by line.